# Mapping values from one DataFrame to another

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out some fast and clean way to map values from one `DataFrame` `A` to another. Let say I have `DataFrame` like this one:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
1   a   b   c   a
2   d   a   e   b   a
3   a   c
4   b   e   e
```

And now I want to change those letter codes to actual values. My `DataFrame` `B`with explanations looks like that:

```
    Code    Value
1   a       'House'
2   b       'Bike'
3   c       'Lamp'
4   d       'Window'
5   e       'Car'
```

So far my brute-force approach was to just go through every element in `A` and check with `isin()` the value in `B`. I know that I can also use `Series` (or simple dictionary) as an `B` instead of `DataFrame` and use for example `Code` column as a index. But still I would need to use multiple loops to map everything.

Is there any other nice way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another alternative is [map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html). Although it requires looping over columns, if I didn't mess up the tests, it is still faster than replace:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list("abcdef"), (1000, 1000)))
B = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                  'Value': ["'House'", "'Bike'", "'Lamp'", "'Window'", "'Car'"]})
B = B.set_index("Code")["Value"]
```

---

```
%timeit A.replace(B)
1 loop, best of 3: 970 ms per loop
```

---

```
C = pd.DataFrame()

%%timeit
for col in A:
    C[col] = A[col].map(B).fillna(A[col])
1 loop, best of 3: 586 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
A.replace(B.set_index('Code')['Value'])
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame(
    {'C1': ['a', 'd', 'a', 'b'],
     'C2': ['b', 'a', 'c', 'e'],
     'C3': ['c', 'e', '', 'e'],
     'C4': ['a', 'b', '', ''],
     'C5': ['', 'a', '', '']})
B = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                  'Value': ["'House'", "'Bike'", "'Lamp'", "'Window'", "'Car'"]})
print(A.replace(B.set_index('Code')['Value']))
```

yields

```
         C1       C2      C3       C4       C5
0   'House'   'Bike'  'Lamp'  'House'         
1  'Window'  'House'   'Car'   'Bike'  'House'
2   'House'   'Lamp'                          
3    'Bike'    'Car'   'Car'
```