# efficiently mapping values in pandas from a 2nd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to best understand how to use a 2nd file/dataframe to efficiently map values when these values are provided as encoded and there is a label I want to map to it.  Think of this 2nd file as a data dictionary that translates the values in the first dataframe.

For example

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b/raw/5f23f993cd87c283ce766e7ac6b329ee7cc2e1d1/mtcars.csv') 

data_dictionary = pd.DataFrame({'columnname' : ['vs','vs', 'am','am'], 'code'  : [0,1,0,1], 'label':['vs_is_0','vs_is_1','am_is_0','am_is_1'] })
```

Now, I want to be able replace the values in the 'columnname' in the first dataset according to the mapping 'code' with the accurate 'label'.   If a value is found in one and not the other, nothing happens.

Currently my approach is as follows but I feel it is very ineffecient and suboptimal.  Keep in mind I could have 30-40 columns each with 2-200 values I'd want replaced with this vlookup like replacement:

```
 for each_colname in dataset.columns.tolist():
     lookup_values = data_dictionary.query("columnname=={}".format(each_colname))

     # and then doing a merge...
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried a left join?

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686052/mapping-values-from-one-dataframe-to-another

Answer (score 1):

First you can create a mapper dict and then apply this to your dataset.

```
mapper = (
    data_dictionary.groupby('columnname')
    .apply(lambda x: dict(x.values.tolist()))
    .to_dict()
)

for e in mapper.keys():
    df[e] = df[e].map(mapper[e]).combine_first(df[e])
```

Update to handle mismatching datatypes:

```
mapper = (
    data_dictionary.groupby('columnname')
    .apply(lambda x: dict(x.astype(str).values.tolist()))
    .to_dict()
)

for e in mapper.keys():
    df[e] = df[e].astype(str).map(mapper[e]).combine_first(df[e])
```

Comment: this is very helpful, ty.  Curious if there is a way to ignore on datatype?  for example in my mapper creation sometimes the integers are being converted to strings.  In other examples, the column in the 'df' may be string but the mapper may be int.